# Saving a new unicode character in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode, characters, symbols

I'm wondering if it's possible to save a new unicode character (e.g. 2B95 which is the black right arrow) in the list of the microsoft word symbols. Online I found only how to type a symbol by using its unicode coding ("code" then press Alt+X).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The special characters dialog only allows the selection of characters available in the selected font. Codepoints of unimplemented characters are not offered for selection. To make the character 2B95 available, you need to install and select a true type font that implements the character.

For example you could use the [BabelStone Shapes Font](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Shapes.html) by downloading and installing the [BabelStoneShapes.ttf](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Download/BabelStoneShapes.ttf). Please note the [license](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/BabelStoneOFL.txt).

Comment: Once you do this, you could save this as a formatted AutoCorrect entry.

Comment: Hello @MikeF thank you very much for your reply; it's vary helpful